# Choose second var array in a list

Tags: c#

How do I choose the second var array in the list? array[i+1] chooses the second column but I want to begin with the second row of the array. So I would like to disregard the first row, since this contains the column names.
Code:

```
foreach(var array in list)
{
    var NewRow = table.NewRow();
    for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.Count; i++) 
    {
        NewRow[columnNames[i]] = array[i];
    }
    table.Rows.Add(NewRow);
}
```

EDIT: Whole method

```
 private DataTable ConvertListToDataTable(List<WindowsFormsApplication1.ServiceReference1.ArrayOfString> list)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        List<string> columnNames = list[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.Count; i++)
    {
        table.Columns.Add(columnNames[i].ToString());
    }

        foreach (var array in list)

        {
            var NewRow = table.NewRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.Count; i++)
            {
                NewRow[columnNames[i]] = array[i];

            }

            table.Rows.Add(NewRow);
        }
    return table;
}
```

Comment: what is list? how is it initialized or what values does list variable contain?

Comment: Of which type are `list`, and ``columnNames`? We need more code

Comment: try foreach(var array in list.Skip(1))

Comment: glad to help :-). Please accept one of the answers below (I suggest James's answer since he specifies another alternative).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Skip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358985%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
foreach (var array in list.Skip(1))
{
    ...
}
```

Or alternatively, stick with a basic `for` loop and just start at `1`

```
for (var i = 1; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: @C4ud3x I've not copied anyone, it looks like woz & I have a very similar answer but if you want to get technical....I posted my answer first :) Also, the edit made to my answer by woz wasn't *really* necessary so I've rolled it back.

Comment: @James oops sorry, I thought I was editting my own answer, haha. I did add the link first ;)

Comment: if you really want to get technical, I suggested Skip(1) in the comments a few seconds before you posted your question, but still suggested your answer to be accepted...

Comment: @ZoharPeled your short comment is quicker to write than my answer + examples ;) Regardless, it appears everyone had the same idea...

Comment: I know both of you was busy writing your answers when I posted the comment, that's why I didn't bother to write an answer myself :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Skip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358985%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
    foreach (var array in list.Skip(1))
    {
        var NewRow = table.NewRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.Count; i++)
        {
            NewRow[columnNames[i]] = array[i];
        }

        table.Rows.Add(NewRow);
    }
```

Don't forget to add `using System.Linq;` at the top of the file.

Comment: To be fair, Zohar mentioned an answer first, but there are only two or three ways to solve this simple problem, so it's not surprising three people thought of simliar answers all at once.

Comment: The first posts were looking very different. Then suddenly the whole post matched to the other. With linked "Skip" and `:` and all whitespaces. Strange coincidence. But anyway, wasnt my purpose to bring trouble because of that. :)